# Disable the subsections in the agenda slide, but keep navigation tree

Tags: beamer

I want to show the sections and  disable the subsections of the `background` in the `agenda` slide. As a consequence I do not want to lose the navigation tree in the following  (related projects, technologies, requirements, and potential tools) slides as shown the second screen shot. How can I get that to work?

[image]

[image]

**Tex code**

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usetheme{Antibes}
\usecolortheme[named=Maroon]{structure} 
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\title{Test}
\author{Alex XYZ}
\institute{University XYZ}
\date{20.01.16}



\begin{document}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Agenda}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%5

\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
\end{frame}


\section{Background}

\subsection{Related Projects}
\begin{frame}{Related Projects: Waze}


\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\subsection{Technologies}
\begin{frame}{Technologies}

\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\subsection{Requirements}
\begin{frame}{Requirements}

\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\subsection{Potential Tool}
\begin{frame}{Potential Tool}

\end{frame}

\section{System Design and Database}
\begin{frame}{System Design and Database}
Content of database.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you have some code to provide? ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Sorry it was my mistake I forgot to add the code :(

Comment: How about `\tableofcontents[hidesubsections]` ?

Comment: @samcarter: Please add the answer ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beamer has a build in mechanism to hide subsections in the toc:

```
\tableofcontents[hidesubsections]
```

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usetheme{Antibes}
\usecolortheme[named=Maroon]{structure} 
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\title{Test}
\author{Alex XYZ}
\institute{University XYZ}
\date{20.01.16}



\begin{document}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Agenda}
\tableofcontents[hidesubsections]
\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%5

\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
\end{frame}


\section{Background}

\subsection{Related Projects}
\begin{frame}{Related Projects: Waze}


\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\subsection{Technologies}
\begin{frame}{Technologies}

\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\subsection{Requirements}
\begin{frame}{Requirements}

\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\subsection{Potential Tool}
\begin{frame}{Potential Tool}

\end{frame}

\section{System Design and Database}
\begin{frame}{System Design and Database}
Content of database.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]